# How does superuser install app to run for normal user?

Tags: macos, mac

As admin (root) for a group of computers, I have to now install a content filter on a shared Mac, to first catch illegal downloads, and to prevent future peer to peer DL by monitoring.  I can install the OSX app for myself (as admin) and have it run for any new users, but I have to have it installed and enabled it for existing users.
How can I install an OSX app, to run for normal users, when it requires that it be install as admin (root) for each user?

Comment: How many users? If it's not many, `su` may be the way to go.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Do you want to add LaunchAgents/Login Items/Dock Items/... to your users' accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about your specific situation (do all computer have the same usernames, do you have Remote Desktop, etc...) I would say there are two possibilities:

1. Open (but do not install) the installer on your computer and go to File > Show Files and see what files are being installed. There is a way to extract these, and you could place each one in the desired location on each client computer via whatever distribution method you choose.
2. I believe Remote Desktop can install an application as a specific user, and multiple users at the same time.

Comment: He's likely an admin on each of the machines, but needs to *enable* the software for the other user accounts.